# How to translate 「まだ行ったことのないアメリカや日本に行ってみたいです」?

Tags: translation, particle-の, relative-clauses

I am not sure if I understood this sentence right

> まだ行ったことのないアメリカや日本に行ってみたいです。

I got it like: "I want to visit places where I've never been such as America and Japan".

And why is there の?

**Edit**: Thanks to the links now I know why there is の

But I'm still unsure about the right translation for that sentence.

Comment: Where are you getting the "such as"?

Comment: I got it from や, but only just now I noticed that I'm wrong, because や I translated as "and", so basically there is no "such as". 
But then again, what is right translation for this sentence?

Comment: That 「や」 does have the nuance of "such as" in all honesty.

Comment: @非回答者 Thanks that's helpful. I guess if と instead, then no "such as"?

Comment: if I'm not wrong you use [と] when you group multiple nouns together in a complete list. Like except those 2 countries you don't want to visit anything else.

Comment: @virmaior That is correct.  OP's translation is actually good already.  The small problem that might arise if you used "such as" in your TL, you would have to use a word like "places" or "countries", which is NOT used in the original.  If an absolute literal TL is not required, OP's TL captures perfectly the nuance of the original.

Answer (score 0):

I'd translate this as : I'd like to visit places in America and Japan that I've never been to before.

This seems to be an answer to a previous query.  As with many Japanese sentences, the "proper" translation is very dependant on the context.

行ったことのないアメリカ seems to me that the person has been to America before, but is talking about places in America that they haven't *yet* visited.
A literal translation might be "The America that I haven't visited"

As for #2, I don't have a perfect answer because I'm not a student of grammar, but there is a slight change of nuance between の and が here.
が　makes it sound more like the person has never been to America at all.

Comment: Can someone tell me why my answer was voted down?  There is still no accepted answer and I believe that my answer at the very least added to the understanding of nuances in the sentence as well as pointing out that context could change the meaning.
Maybe someone could explain what was wrong with my response so I can provide better responses next time.